# VueJS reusable watchers

Tags: vue.js

I have a pagination object in `data` like this:

```
pagination: {
  page: 1,
  limit: 10,
  from: 1,
  to: this.limit,
  total: null
}
```

and I'm using this object in every list I create. There's a component, handling pagination stuff and I pass this `pagination` object as `v-model`. I created a watcher for this `pagination` object in the parent component and I have to rewrite this watcher in every list. Is there a way to write this watcher just once and use it anywhere I want?

Here is the watcher:

```
watch: {
  pagination: {
    handler () {
      if (this.pagination.page > this.totalPages) {
        this.pagination.page = this.totalPages
      }
      this.getFields()
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `mixin`

A mixin can behave like a vue component, which you can include in every component that you want like this -

```
var mixin = {
  data: function () {
    return {
      pagination: {
        page: 1,
        limit: 10,
        from: 1,
        to: this.limit,
        total: null
      }
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  mixins: [mixin],
  data: function () {
    return {
      pagination: {
        page: 2
      }
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    console.log(this.pagination.limit)
    // 10 -> takes from the mixin
    console.log(this.pagination.page)
    // 2 -> takes from the current component as it overrides the mixin
  }
})
```

Similarly you can use your watcher in a mixin!
[Check it here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

Hope it helps!!